# Can't post a variable with ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm trying to post a variable with ajax to php, but couldn't did it. What is the wrong in this code?

-- test.php --

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="test.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['variable']))
            {
                $id = $_POST['variable'];
                print_r($id);
            }
            else {
                print_r("???");
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

-- test.js --

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'test.php',
    data: { variable : 5 },
    success: function(data) {
        alert("success!" + variable);
    }
});
```

-- File Structure --

```
App
|  - test.js
|  - test.php
```

Comment: what event are you intending to have trigger the sending?

Comment: `variable` is `undefined` in your `success` callback.

Comment: Voting to close because the problem is caused by a typo. You have a variable called `data` in your success function  (`function(data) {`) but on the next line you refer to it as `variable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your success function you are trying to alert `variable`(which is invalid) You should use `data` as specified in your `success: function(data)`.

The `data` is returned from your `test.php` file as output.

--

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'test.php',
    data: { variable : 5 },
    success: function(data) {
        alert("success!" + data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow.